# Split numbers using regular expressions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split numbers using a regular exression in JS. E.g.:

My Input is
 1000000
 100000
 10000
 1000

My Output is
    10,000,00
    1,00,000
    10,000
    1000

I'm using:

```
replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')
```

But it is not working on `(100,000)`.It split on 3 digits only but i want like             (1,00,000)

Comment: It would be far simpler to use `string.split(',')` than splitting using regex.

Comment: It would be helpful if you give an example of input and desired output

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight: i think he's adding commas, not removing them...

Comment: Actually given input like that 1000000
100000
10000
1000

Comment: @Dotnet please edit the question and update the infor there. otherwise you're question is likely to be closed...

Comment: @TilwinJoy i gave all information .i need solution ....

Comment: You're trying to format a number, so use a number formatting library, many of which include options for your preferred type of comma insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Right, now that some context has been provided as to what you actually want, I can legitimately tell you that you cannot use regex to do what you're thinking of in JavaScript.  Instead, it would be better to loop over it as a string.

```
var string,out;
<string gets assigned somewhere>

out = '';
for (var i=string.length-1,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++) {
    if (j % 3 === 0) out = ',' + out;
    out = string[i] + out;
}
```

Comment: it is not working show that "Undefined" Error Message

Comment: @Dotnet I forgot to initialize out; I've fixed the code.